# Check Active Internet Connection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Obviously this is a Javascript problem. As javascript are already loaded to the server, I was wondering if there is way to check whether there is active internet connection or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could send an ajax request and see if it gets a response.
With jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    alert('Connection.');
  },
  error: function(data) {
    alert('No Connection.');
  }
});
```

Comment: Good logic, but are you sure the page does not return a HTTP error message instead of page...

Comment: Yes, you have to be sure the test page does not return a HTTP error. It's probably a good idea to display an error like "Can't connect to example.com server" rather than "You have no internet connection."